# Setting sticky bit to mounted folder

Tags: permissions, mount, chmod

I mounted a folder under /media/datasets, owner and group group are specified as root:

```
$ ll /media/
drwxrwxrwx 31 root root  4,0K Apr 19 19:55 datasets
```

Now I want to set the sticky bit to that directory to prevent the users from deleting each others folders, so the rights should look like this:

```
drwxrwxrwt
```

However when I do

```
sudo chmod o+t /media/datasets
```

It says

```
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/media/datasets’: Operation not permitted
```

I can execute the command above on folders inside `/media/datasets` but not on `/media/datasets` itself. I'm not sure why. Anyone an idea how to fix this?

Not sure if this is important but the `datasets` folder is located on a synology fileserver (NAS) and is mounted on multiple machines simultaneously.

Comment: Might the underlying file system of your mounted folder possibly not support sticky bits or Unix permissions in general? Do you know what type it is?

Comment: Permissions should be fine, since I can set permissions for subfolders . I checked the [synology NAS settings](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/AdminCenter/file_share_privilege_nfs). It says "Squash: Map all users to admin: Assigns access privileges to all users of NFS client equivalent to the admin user access privileges on your system." Maybe that is a problem, I will try to change that setting once the NAS is being maintained and report the result here

Comment: Have you tried `sudo chmod o+t /media/datasets` before mounting the file system here?